# Center an object exactly in the center of the screen

Tags: c++, c, geometry

I'm trying to center an object exactly in the center of the screen. The screen is 320X480 and

the object is 25X25. The algorithm i already tried to build is this pseudo function code:

```
void (int x, int y, int object ){

int position = (x-y)/2;

Update_X(object ,  position);

}
```

but that would only center it in the X-axis, i want also have the Y-axis centered. How do i

do that?? is there any algorithm that can be used in C or C++?

Comment: `(screenWidth - objWidth) / 2` and `(screenHeight - objHeight) / 2` should work to get the commonly required top-left corner.

Comment: (screenWidth - objWidth) / 2 = x and (screenHeight - objHeight) / 2 = y right?

Comment: Yes. If it helps, you can think of `screenWidth/2 - objWidth/2`. The first part gets the centre of the screen horizontally, and the second part goes left half of the object to get where the left side should be.

Comment: People are now asking basic arithmetic questions at SO? Draw a box representing the screen on a piece of paper, draw another box representing the object, then *figure out where the upper left corner is*. "that would only center it in the X-axis" -- No, it wouldn't do anything of the sort; `(x-y)/2` is nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic "centering equation" is simply:

```
center = (total_space - needed) / 2;
```

This divides the remaining space in half, meaning it's as much on the left as on the right, or above and below. It assumes the position is relative to the "leftmost" (or "upper" for Y) edge of the object being centered.

For a very simpe example, consider horizontally centering an object with `needed = 6` into a `total_space` of 14:

```
(14 - 6) / 2 = 4
```

so, attempting a graphical display:

```
    needed = 6
     /    \
|----XXXXXX----|   The 6 X:s are centered, 
|              |   with 4 dashes on either
 \            /    side. The total space
  \          /     between the |:s is 14.
   \        /
total_space = 14
```

This is for one dimension only so you have to compute it twice: once for X and once for Y. That the two should be independent of each other *should* be obvious from the fact that they are *dimensions*; that's what dimensions do! :)

So, plugging in your values we get:

```
center_x = (320 - 25) / 2 = 147

center_y = (480 - 25) / 2 = 227
```

I rounded down; it's not evenly divisible in either case so you're going to have to pick a rounding method. In C and C++, just using integer arithmetic will get you this automatically since the division will be done on integers.

Comment: what the best rounding method in C or C++?

Comment: something like: (num > 0.0) ? floor(num + 0.5) : ceil(num - 0.5); ? maybe

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz, `std::round(num)`, but make sure you only do that if you're not already getting integer truncation.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz "what the best rounding method" -- The answer already states "just using integer arithmetic will get you this automatically". You should only do some other sort of rounding if you have good reason to. If, for instance, you are using device independent units, you should round to the nearest exact pixel.